# React - get random color in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component in my React project where I'm trying to pass a random color via props however it's not working (the random numbers work just fine though).  I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly here and my GoogleFu + StackO searches have not rendered an answer.  Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly?

My code is:

```
    getRandomColor(){
    let colorValues = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
    return colorValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorValues.length)];
  }

  generatePulse(i) {
    const props = {
      key: i,
      top: this.getRandomNumber(-385, 556),
      left: this.getRandomNumber(-1000, 2500),
      scale: `scale(${this.getRandomNumber(1, 20)})`,
      fade: `fade ${this.getRandomNumber(1, 60)}s`,
      scaling: `scaling ${this.getRandomNumber(1, 25)}s`,
      background: `background ${this.getRandomColor}`,
    }
    return (<Stars {...props} />)
  }
```

And it should affect the background here (I'm aware I have 2 animations running, that's another problem I need to solve)

```
    class Stars extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Starholder>
        <Star style={{
          left: this.props.left + 'px',
          top: this.props.top + 'px',
          transform: this.props.scale,
          background: this.props.background,
          animation: this.props.fade + ' normal forwards ease-in-out',
          animation: this.props.scaling + ' infinite alternate',}}></Star>
      </Starholder>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might just be missing the `()` when calling `this.getRandomColor`?

Comment: Yes, you are missing the `()`, also remove `background` after the colon so it is `background: \`${this.getRandomColor()}\``

Comment: guys, thank you!!!